# How can I introduce values to a vector in random positions in R?

Tags: r, random, vector

I'm just starting to learn R, and my assignment was to create *a vector of 10000* values with *normal distribution*, `mean = 0` and `sd = 100`. Which I did.

```
x <- rnorm(10000, mean = 0, sd = 100)
```

But now I'm asked to introduce `values between 500 and 700` at 1000 random positions in that vector.

Can anyone help me?

Comment: I don't understand : how could you introduce 1000 values between the 500 and 700 position of a vector ? Also, what did you try already that didn't work ?

Comment: @Arun ah ok, so it would mean that 500 to 700 is the values to be inserted, not the positions at which you have to insert them...

Comment: @user2016382 As it seems difficult to understand the question, I'll just give you one hint for your homework : take a look at the `sample` function.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

If you mean to replace 1000 elements in the `x` vector with  *values between 500 and 700*, you first need to generate these 1000 elements:

```R
r <- runif(1000, min=500, max=700)
```

I am assuming here that random values are *uniformly* between 500 and 700.

Then you need to select places to put these values in:

```R
idx <- sample(10000, 1000)
```

Finally, replace the values at these places:

```R
x[ idx ] <- r
```

Finally, to see the results of your action:

```R
hist(x)
```

It should look like: [image: Histogram of x]

Comment: Thanks for the comments. I have simplified the call to `sample` and improved the wording.

Comment: Yes thank you! this solves it. I'm sorry I didn't explained better the question. Again thank you.